# SQL Remove duplicates on Oldest date

Tags: sql, duplicates

I am new to SQL and trying to put an Excell report together that would return only the youngest entry if duplicates are found in another field.

```
SELECT distinct [Barcode]
      ,[Code]
      ,[Description]
      ,[TransactionType]
      ,[Date]
      ,[From Qty]
      ,[DocumentReference]
      ,[DocumentNumber]
      ,[Site]
  FROM [GRANITE].[dbo].[Report_App_Transactions]where TransactionType='pick'
```

My aim is to find duplicates in "Barcode" and only return the youngest value as per "Date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from [GRANITE].[dbo].[Report_App_Transactions] r1
inner join 
(
    select barcode, max(date) as mdate
    from [GRANITE].[dbo].[Report_App_Transactions]
    group by barcode
) r2 on r1.barcode = r1.barcode and r2.mdate = r1.date
where r1.TransactionType='pick'
```

Comment: +1 but "duplicates are found in another field" suggests the OP wants to check for duplicates on more than just `(barcode)`

Comment: THANKS! I sat for 3 days utilising GOOGLE with no luck!